# Wrap Panel Item separators

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

Is it possible to separate items in a wrap panel with a horizontal line and to have the line wrap with the items (i.e. line from top row last item to next row first item?
The line width should be able to be set at run time, and the line that wraps should have additional feature of arrow heads showing direction of flow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `ItemsControl` which has it's `ItemsPanelTemplate` drawn as a WrapPanel. Then you could add your lines/arrows to the `ItemsPanel.ItemTemplate`